# IndexError: list assignment index out of range Python 3 What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

```
elif letterGuess in letterList: # if the letter is one the word characters
  count = 1
  print (letterGuess, ' is in the word!')
  for n in letterList:
      if n == letterGuess: # replaces the dashes with letters
          dash[count - 1] = letterGuess # takes the dash in position and replaces
      count += 1
  count = 0
```

This is a part of some code for hangman.
It says the error is within the line:

```
dash[count - 1] = letterGuess
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that `count` is greater than to the length of `dash`. Since we don't know what `dash` is supposed to contain, it is hard to say more.

Comment: dash is supposed to contain a dash for every character of the word so if the word is 'hiya' then dash is '----'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dash could only be of length 0 or not iterable.Print dash and cout derectly  befor the line that causes the eror.